# Sort by two columns rails, but prioritize one if a field is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

So I have a table with a column priority_n. Pretend there's 5 items in that table. Two with nil as priority_n, and the other three have 1, 2, 3 in priority_n.

So I'd like to do a where(priority_n: nil).order(published_at: :desc) combined with where.not(priority_n: nil).order(priority_n: :asc). So I want the nil ones at the beginning of the active record relations, and then the prioritized ones after them. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick:

```
class MyModel

  scope :with_priority, -> { where.not(priority: nil).reorder(:priority) }
  scope :without_priority, -> { where(priority: nil).reorder(published_at: :desc) }

  def self.special_order
    without_priority.to_a + with_priority.to_a
  end
end
```

Now, you can call: `MyModel.special_order` that returns an array ordered like you ask.